# Parameter is not valid when i retrieve Image

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

```
string nama = dgGambar1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["nama_gambar"].FormattedValue.ToString();
btnTambahDataBarang.Enabled = false;
koneksi.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM and_bwi_gambar WHERE nama_gambar = '" + nama + "'", koneksi);
MySqlDataReader rd;
rd = command.ExecuteReader();
while (rd.Read())
{
  txtGambar1.Text = rd.GetValue(2).ToString();
  byte[] img = (byte[])rd.GetValue(3);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
  pbGambar1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
koneksi.Close();
```

when i retrieve an image whose size is more than 250kb, it always get an error 'parameter argument invalid'

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: You should use bind arguments instead of text interpolation in new MySqlCommand to avoid SQL injection.  Also, name the columns rather than using *.

Comment: @RobertHarvey line error at Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: The phrase "Parameter Argument Invalid" doesn't Google.  Please provide the exact wording of the error message you are getting.

Comment: @Ferdy Did you validate the image data isn't corrupt. The method Image.FromStream return an ArgumentException when the stream you're passing does not have a valid image format.

Comment: @RobertHarvey sorry my bad, it should be 'parameter is not valid' not 'parameter argument invalid'

Comment: @4d875752c6a784cb21d90a2818c6e0 ya i was validate  image data is not corupt, i was testing too with other image whose have size more than 250 kb.

Comment: @Ferdy I tried to replicate your case and the thing is you're loading PNG larger more than usual. So, you might need to use ImageConverter to solve it:

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img))
{
    var ic = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
    var img = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom(ms.ReadAllBytes());
    pbGambar1.Image = img;
}


I hope this works for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 options to solve this:

1. using image converter:

```
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])rd.GetValue(3);
    using(var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        var ic = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
        pbGambar1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)ic.ConvertFrom(stream.ReadAllBytes());
    }
```

2. or try to load up binary data into memory stream first:

```
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])rd.GetValue(3);
    using(var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        memStream.Position = 0;
        pbGambar1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Parameter is not valid" exception thrown when I executed the second code